# help me edit this jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQ:

```
$(function() {
    if($('span').css('color')=='rgb(250, 0, 0)' ||
       $('span').css('color')=='#fa0000') {
         $('span').before('hello ');
       }
});
```

it work with this html:

```
<span style="color: #fa0000">Ann</span>
```

but it do not work with:

```
<span><span style="color: #fa0000">Ann</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `.css('color')`, it's only getting the color of the 1st span.  You want to check the color of each span.  Try this:

```
$('span').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var color = $this.css('color');
    if (color == 'rgb(250, 0, 0)' || color == '#fa0000') {
        $this.before('hello ');
    }
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y7nVZ/

Answer (score 6):

Your selector is fine, but the way `.css` works is it will "pop" the first element off the stack and work with it. Because you have nested spans, the first tag is only received in, ignoring the nested span.

Try using an `.each()` or changing your selector

---

#### In Action ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rPsYj/))

```
<span style="color:#FF00FF;">
    <span style="color:#fa0000">
        Brad Christie
    </span>
</span>

$(function(){
    var spanColor = $('span').css('color');

    // You'll notice the color shown is that of the first span (#FF00FF) and
    // not of the nested one because .css() takes the first element that matched
    // and returns the color of that element.
    $('body').append(spanColor); // output: rgb(255,0,255)

});
```

Comment: To be clear, only the **get** of `.css` will pop off the first element (as you wouldn't want to merge 2+ entries). However, a **set** will set as many as the selector will match.

Answer (score 1):

Brad's answer covers the reason why the current code isn't working - you need to use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) to iterate over each element.  You could also use the [jQuery.Color v2.0b1](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/31/jquery-color-v2-beta-1-released/) to assist in the color detection and do this:

```
$('span').each(function() {
  if ($.Color(this, 'color').is("#fa0000")) { 
    $(this).before('hello');
  }
});
```

See the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v5N7j/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  if($('span:first-child').css('color')=='rgb(250, 0, 0)'||$('span:first-child').css('color')=='#fa0000'){
    $('span').before('hello ');
  }
})
```

You can also you [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method if you want to colorize nested span.